# I'm stuck trying to create a simple point-and-click game in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and decided that I wanted to create a game of some sort.

The game itself is really, really simple.

**Basically, you're presented with an image. And 7 choices. If your choice matches the picture, you get one point and get shown the next picture.**

Also: as soon as you click your answer, no matter if you're right or wrong, two pictures will popup beside the picture and 'spoil' the answer for you. If you were right - it displays a message saying you were right. If you were wrong - there's supposed to be a message for that.

This is where I've run into a couple of problems.

I'm able to run this if statement:

```
if($("div").hasClass('sadness') && $("img").hasClass('sadness'))
```

But I'm not able to run:

```
if(!$("div").hasClass('sadness') && $("img").hasClass('sadness'))
```

**It's easier shown than told.**

Note: my stuff doesn't really align well @ jsFiddle, but it's the jQuery code that's important.

http://jsfiddle.net/WEAt6/

I would deeply appreciate if you guys took your time and looked through my code, I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your fiddle, I think I can see the problem: you don't want to be selecting objects with `$("div")` : this will return all the divs in your page. This would explain why you are always getting `$("div").hasClass('sadness')` returning true: you are always selecting your "happy" div. Try using the `$(this)` selector within your function instead.

Comment: $(this) is what you need! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A little busy, so I'm not looking deep, but have you broken it down?

What is the result when you separate it into two ifs?

```
if(!$("div").hasClass('sadness')){
    if($("img").hasClass('sadness')){
```

ALSO: if your image is contained in your div (assumed), is it inheriting class status? If so, the div not having 'sadness' makes the image not have 'sadness', and vice versa.

Comment: you might want to separate in css the 'sadness' class, one for div, one for img